# Query for effective date based on related table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out a query that targets records in a table that is related to the table where the effectiveDates are stored.

Let's say I have these three tables:

```
tblProjects
-----------
id 

tblTickets
----------
id 
projectID 
ticketNumber
ticketDate

tblRates
--------
id
projectID
effectiveDate
payRate
```

What I'm trying to do is create a query that tests the effectiveDate of the Rates table against the ticketDate and finds the latest effectiveDate that is <= ticketDate. Finding the latest is important as it's possible for there to be several different Rate values that apply to the project.

So tblTickets might have:

```
id      projectId        ticketDate        ticketNumber
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            1            2016/08/11            990
2            1            2016/09/12            991
3            1            2016/10/22            992
4            1            2016/10/23            993
5            2            2016/08/15            750
6            2            2016/09/08            751
```

and tblRates might have:

```
id      projectId        effectiveDate        Rate
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            1            2016/08/01          $50  
2            1            2016/10/01          $75
3            2            2016/06/01          $65
```

If I were to query for all tickets with the projectId = 1, I would want to see something like this:

```
projectId        ticketNumber        TicketDate            Rate
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                 990            2016/08/11            $50
    1                 991            2016/09/12            $50
    1                 992            2016/10/12            $75
    1                 993            2016/10/23            $75
```

I'm not even really sure where to start. I could query for the MAX of the effectiveDate but that will only return the 10/12 and 10/23 records in the example above. I could also simply query for everything that is <= the TicketDate but that would return duplicates as both 08/01 and 10/01 fall under that criteria.

A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Here's my current query. It's returning duplicates of all records for each of the Rates.

```
SELECT 
      vRates.projectId
    , tblTickets.TicketNumber
    , tblTickets.TicketDate
    , vRates.Rate
    , vRates.effectiveDate

FROM (
     ( SELECT  
              vTempRates.effectiveFrom
            , vTempRates.projectId
            , vRates.Rate
      FROM    tblRates AS vTempRates 
      INNER JOIN
            ( SELECT  
                  projectId
                , MAX(effectiveFrom) AS effectiveDate
                , Rate
              FROM  tblRates
              GROUP BY projectId, Rate
            ) AS vRates
      ON vTempRates.projectId = vRates.projectId 
            AND vTempRates.effectiveFrom = vRates.effectiveDate

     ) AS vRates 
       INNER JOIN tblProjects 
          ON vRates.projectId = tblProjects.id) 
       INNER JOIN tblTickets 
          ON tblProjects.id = tblTickets.projectId
WHERE (((tblProjects.id)=1));
```

Comment: What database are you using (including version)?

Comment: A mix between MS Access 2010 and SQL Server 2016. I'm writing the query in Access though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Access 2013

```
select      t.*
           ,(select top 1 r.Rate from tblRates r where r.projectid = t.projectid and r.effectiveDate <= t.ticketDate order by r.effectiveDate desc) as Rate
from        tblTickets      t   
where       t.projectid = 1
;
```

Comment: @user2170742, please check yourself. I've just verified the correctness of the answer on Access 2013 and it worked fine, as is.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct even though this didn't work for me in Access 2010. Perhaps they changed some things in 2013, but I decided to change my approach and use T-SQL through ADODB instead. Using this approach worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I went through your question and I guess if I am correct it would be really easy to do this with the following:

```
Select effectivedate from Rates R join Projects p on R.projectId= p.id join 
Tickets T on T.projectId = p.id where
effectivedate<= t.ticketdate
order by effectivedate desc
limit 1;
```

This query basically will select the corresponding effective date. Now the order by clause will have the output sorted with respect to the the effective dates that you have taken in the format latest to least latest and then the limit 1 will just return the latest date.

Also in case you want to have the last 3 latest  dates you can always increase the number in the limit keyword like so:

```
limit 3
```

This will return the last 3 latest dates.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Does this not just return the most recent effectiveDate?

For example. If effectiveDates are 
2016/09/01
2016/10/31

it will return 2016/10/31 regardless of whether a ticketDate is 2016/09/25...

Comment: I'm only getting the latest two tickets being returned using this. The earlier two (per the example: 990 and 991) are not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tic.projectId projectId,tic.ticketNumber ticketNumber , tic.ticketDate ticketDate ,(SELECT top 1 Rate FROM tblRates WHERE ticketDate  >= effectiveDate AND tblRates.projectId = Tic.projectId ORDER BY effectiveDate DESC) Rate
FROM tblTickets  Tic WHERE Tic.projectId = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both this, and @Dudu answers won't work - at least not in Access. It apparently doesn't like that tblTickets isn't included in the subquery SELECT statement...

Comment: It's working fine man.Just using tblTickets columns only in sub query

Comment: I'm continuously getting an error: The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'tblTickets.ticketDate' as a valid field name or expression.

If I remove that SELECT statement, the query runs.

If I change the FROM statement to: FROM tblRates INNER JOIN tblTickets ON tblRates.projectId = tblTickets.projectId

I get an error: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: @Mansoor: It should work, but you may have to use the "AS" syntax: `FROM tblTickets AS Tic` and `.. AS Rate`.